# Harddisk won't mount

Tags: hard-drive, mount

Friend of mine dropped a HDD on the floor and every since the HDD won't mount when connected. It just makes this spinning noise inside for about two rounds and then it goes quiet.
Obviously, he wants to salvage the data but I said to him I'll see what I can do
knowing the chance of recovery is pretty slim with HDD that won't mount.

Was I right about this ? Is there anything I can try I may not know about ?

I tried to run gparted on it as I know gparted can detect disks that aren't mounted but connected. But no luck.

Comment: If it's making a lot of noise, chances are it's crashed. If you look up crashed HDD, there are tons of tutorials, but I'm not sure how much success they have.

Comment: It doesn't make "a lot of noise" I can hear it tries to spin but after 2 rounds it gives up. But I know I shouldn't hear the noise it makes. It sounds like the needle inside bumps into something.

Comment: Take it to a data recovery service… very expensive & no guarantee of success. Next time, have a backup.

Answer (score 1):

If the disk is making noises then DON'T TURN IT ON.
You are perhaps just continuing on scratching the disk surface and making
less likely the successful recovery of the data.

Send the disk to a professional recovery specialist that can treat each disk
platter and recover its data. Be prepared for a large bill, so better do
some market research.